# Es necesario crear una página por producto para tener SEO, ecommerce hecho con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Voy a crear un ecommerce dónde se venderán productos farmacéuticos digamos que son 50 productos diferentes.

Los productos y sus datos los voy a guardar en firebase.

Mi duda es tengo que crear una página por cada producto?

Se que puedo crear una sola página para la vista del producto y pasarle como parámetro el ID del producto y buscar en la base de datos la data. Pero ¿Eso afectaría en el seo? Osea el navegador va a poder indexar la página con la data.

Lo pregunto por qué e visto que con WordPress siempre se crear una página diferente (o eso es lo que e entendido)

¿Para SEO es recomendable crear una página por producto?

Gracias por leer

Answer (score 0):

Para el SEO es importante que cada producto tenga una URL, lo cual no implica que sea una página diferente necesariamente.

En particular, es importante que la asociación entre URL y producto sea única, para lo cual es importante definir una [URL canónica](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls#rel-canonical-link-method) para el SEO.

Comment: pero si los datos de la página del producto los agrego con JavaScript, Cuando alguien haga una búsqueda en un buscador ya sea Google o firefox, ¿se indexar con los datos y como indexaria está URL https:///ejemplo.com?id=1233 (para que sepa que datos cargar)

Comment: La mayoría de los indexadores actuales cargan la página usando javascript, por lo que si la carga de la página no es muy lenta debería funcionar.

Comment: Mas allá de eso, frameworks como [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) te permiten tener a la vez hacer un solo sitio y tener muchas urls, el usuario recibe una página estática generada en el servidor, que luego se "hidrata" y funciona como una SPA... quizás es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: De acuerdo, en mi paso pienso usar solo JavaScript y como pasarela de pago. Entonces estaría bien usar una sola página para los productos y tener está URL https://ejemplo.com/producto/?id=1231 y a este archivo html y definirle que es una URL canónica. Y no habría mucho problema en la indexsacion?  Es mi primera vez haciendo un ecommerce y lo quiero hacer bien, gracias!